# Using StyleHook in C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I need to create a style hook for TEdit in C++ Builder XE7, in order to override the style color management, as the following [Delphi example](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2012/02/06/changing-the-color-of-edit-controls-with-vcl-styles-enabled/). Could somebody post a complete example in C++ Builder (hook unit, registration and example form)? Thanks!

Comment: Translate the Delphi example

Comment: I posted the question since am unable to translate the Delphi example

Comment: I sympathise, but we are not a translation service. You need to learn enough Delphi to be able to translate code like this. Until you do so, C++Builder is going to be a terribly frustrating tool for you.

Comment: Hi @David, initially I asked for an example, not for translation. Sorry fo the misunderstanding. However I'll do a try, thank you anyway.

Comment: Asking for an example is off topic here also. Sorry. Please read the articles in the [help] that cover this.

Answer (score 1):

A translation of the Delphi example would look something like this:

```cpp
class TEditStyleHookColor : public TEditStyleHook
{
    typedef TEditStyleHook inherited;
private:
    void UpdateColors();
protected:
    virtual void __fastcall WndProc(TMessage &Message);
public:
    __fastcall TEditStyleHookColor(TWinControl *AControl);
};
```

```cpp
#include <Vcl.Styles.hpp>

class TWinControlH : public TWinControl {};

__fastcall TEditStyleHookColor::TEditStyleHookColor(TWinControl *AControl)
    : TEditStyleHook(AControl)
{
    //call the UpdateColors method to use the custom colors
    UpdateColors();
};

//Here you set the colors of the style hook
void TEditStyleHookColor::UpdateColors()
{
    if (Control->Enabled)
    {
        Brush->Color = (static_cast<TWinControlH*>(Control)->Color; //use the Control color
        FontColor = static_cast<TWinControlH*>(Control)->Font->Color;//use the Control font color
    }
    else
    {
        //if the control is disabled use the colors of the style
        TCustomStyleServices *LStyle = StyleServices();
        Brush->Color = LStyle->GetStyleColor(scEditDisabled);
        FontColor = LStyle->GetStyleFontColor(sfEditBoxTextDisabled);
    }
}

//Handle the messages of the control
void __fastcall TEditStyleHookColor::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    switch (Message.Msg)
    {
        case CN_CTLCOLORMSGBOX:
        case CN_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR:
        case CN_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        {
            //Get the colors
            UpdateColors();
            SetTextColor(reinterpret_cast<HDC>(Message.WParam), ColorToRGB(FontColor));
            SetBkColor(reinterpret_cast<HDC>(Message.WParam), ColorToRGB(Brush->Color));
            Message.Result = reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(Brush->Handle);
            Handled = true;
            break;
        }
        case CM_ENABLEDCHANGED:
        {
            //Get the colors
            UpdateColors();
            Handled = false;
            break;
        }
        default:
          inherited::WndProc(Message);
          break;
    }
}

...

TStyleManager::Engine->RegisterStyleHook(__classid(TEdit), __classid(TEditStyleHookColor));
TStyleManager::Engine->RegisterStyleHook(__classid(TMaskEdit), __classid(TEditStyleHookColor));
TStyleManager::Engine->RegisterStyleHook(__classid(TLabeledEdit), __classid(TEditStyleHookColor));
TStyleManager::Engine->RegisterStyleHook(__classid(TButtonedEdit), __classid(TEditStyleHookColor));
```